# How to scroll listview inside a popup?

Tags: jquery-mobile

How can I scrolling listview inside a popup using jQuery Mobile?

```php
<a href="#currency" data-rel="popup" data-role="none" data-inline="true"  data-icon="gear" data-theme="c">Currency</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="currency" data-theme="c">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;" data-theme="c">           
         <?php foreach($currencies as $key => $currency): ?>
            <li><a value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $currency); ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding overflow:scroll or overflow:auto to your inline style on the ul tag?

Comment: overflow:scroll or overflow:auto do not work on mobile devices

Comment: Oh yes, they do, but what you need is this      overflow-y: scroll;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touc